# removing linebreak from array elements Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, line-breaks

I have the following array, declared as "var strArry":

```
 <h4>  ``</h4>,<h4><font color="DarkSalmon">"We</font></h4>,<h4> wo </h4>,<h4><font color="ForestGreen">"'t comment on the</font></h4>,<h4>m . '' </h4>
```

It gives the following output of 5 strings, separated by commas:

``,"We, wo ,"'t comment on the,m . ''

I then call the array to form a continuous string without the commas by using the following command:

```
var htmlElementsforSrcLanguageSentence = htmlElementsforSrcLanguageSentence +strArry.join("");
```

The output it gives below is not what I need:

```
 ``
"We
wo
"'t comment on the
m . ''
```

It is the removing the commas as expected but also placing each element in a new line. This doesn't work as I need to display it as one sentence. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use .toString() and then from there do a .replace() for the commas to be replaced with spaces?

```
var newArray     = new Array("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4");
var newString    = newArray.toString();
var editedString = newString.replace(/,/g, " ");
console.log(editedString);
```

Edit 1:

If you run that in a javascript console it does what you want, i'll go put a jsfiddle together for you.

Edit 2:

[Here is the JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a2ztyL98/)